# Where to find the template for sale emails in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento, html-email, magento-1.8

I can't find where Magento keeps template which generates sales items in the sale emails. I need to change the colour bar on where it holds `Item, Sku, Qty, Subtotal`

[image]

I go to `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourTemplate/layout/` and open `sales.xml`, still can't find any hint of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For the emailed SO line items:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

For the emailed SO items header:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml
```

Copy to your template and modify. Because the email has to be self-contained, the modifications have to be made to the generated html that gets sent.

All other modifications are done through `System -> Transactional Emails` on the admin panel, create a new template based on the stock template and change there.